# wrap from end Bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have two columns with the following structure using Bulma (0.7.1):

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- column 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- column 2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When a user visit my website using a tablet or a mobile, I want my second column to wrap first, i.e. over the first column.

Is there a built-in class in Bulma that does that ? Or do I have to write my own CSS ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out with CSS/Bulma, you can add a `custom-columns` and use `column-reverse` to change the column's order.

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.1/css/bulma.css");

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .custom-columns {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns custom-columns">
  <div class="column box">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="column box">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works ! However, I'm wondering why `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` does not ?

Comment: I guess `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` can't be applied for columns/rows. That's why you have for the `flex-flow` two options, `flex-wrap` and `flex-direction` with differents values and different ways to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.is-multiline` to have a wrap on your column (Bulma)

**With CSS**

```
display: flex;   
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

**With Bulma**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='columns is-multiline'>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <div class="card-image">
        colonne 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        colonne 2
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @LPK, thank you very much for your help ! this is not what I am actually looking for, what I want is to change the order of wrapping of my columns. By default with Bulma, column 1 will get first and column 2 second on mobile, whereas I want column 2 first and then column 1. not sure if I'm clear though, sorry if it isn't.

Comment: @JulesCorb oh my bad, I guess I didn't saw it. And you're clear, I understand now ! :-)